# Creating a kernel driver in VisualStudio

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, kernel, driver

My objective is to make a Windows kernel driver that has the ability to simulate usb peripheral "clicks" from devices such as mice, keyboard, etc. I know for example you can use BlockInput from winuser.h to block inputs (I assume this function is the correct way to approach this from a driver?). But I am not so familiar with generating inputs from such a driver.

Anyways now that we got that back story out of the way my question pertains to which template, I need inside of VisualStudio in order to achieve this. I assume I should make a Filter driver rather than a function driver but which setting do I choose? I see many options, but I know I don't need a "User Mode Driver", but I am not too, sure from there.

One option is "Kernel Mode Driver, USB (KMDF)" but that sounds more like a function driver. So right now, I am thinking the "Kernel Mode Driver (KMDF)" is the best option since that sounds like a filter driver which I know is more flexible and has the ability to communicate with user applications.

Anyways if anything I said was incorrect, please don't hesitate to correct me! Also, just for some context I plan to use the C programming language but changing them from C++ to C is easy enough. Lastly, please let me know which, driver template you suggest me using based on what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure what else I need to provide. I want to make a driver that can a) simulate mouse, keyboard and controller clicks / movement. Then b) be able to block these outputs when they originate from a real usb device. lastly, c) it needs to be able to communicate with user mode applications those are all the requirements. Based on this I concluded I needed a Filter Driver is this correct? If my assumption is correct which driver template, do I need? I think I need "Kernel Mode Driver (KMDF)" is this correct if not which template should I select to start my driver?

Comment: If you think you know the best option, try it. You don't have to full-commit. Just build up one step at a time. If you need your driver to make a HID device show up in Device Manager, then try to make that work. Now work out a basic way to communicate with your driver so you can make it do stuff. Get that working. Now, see if you can make it generate some kind of mouse or keyboard event that affects the OS. If you encounter a roadblock, you can surely take most of your code and try it with the other driver type. If you paralyze yourself with questions before making a start, you'll go nowhere.